# Lisp variable unbound

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, syntax-error, lisp

I'm trying to make a function where after 7 values are entered, they are put into an array and from that array, each element is added to another variable (avg).

I keep getting "The variable AVG is unbound". I don't see where the problem is.

```
(defun readTestScores()
    (let ((examScore 0)
          (avg 0)))
    (setf testScore (make-array 7))

    (format t "~&ENTER EXAM SCORE ~23T: ")
    (setq examScore(read))

    (format t "~&ENTER ALL TEST SCORES ~23T: ")
    (dotimes (i 7)
        (setf (aref testScore i) (read))
    )

    (dotimes (i 7)
        (setq avg (+ avg (aref testScore i)))
    )
)
(readTestScores)
```

Comment: What dialect is this? Common Lisp?

Comment: Yes it is Common Lisp (as far as I know, I just started)

Comment: Your `let` is closed right after you have bound the variables. TO be able to reference `avg` you have the rest of the code in the body of the `let`. The function doesn't return anything. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `let` is incorrect. It should be:

```
(let ((examScore init-value)
      (avg 0))
    let-body)
```

This way you would have declared and initialized two local variables, where `examScore` will be initialized to `init-value`. **However, you have declared `examScore`and defined its initial value as `(avg 0)`**, which would be the result of calling the function `avg` with a parameter of value 0. The `avg` function is probably not defined, since that was not your intention, therefore the unbound message.

Comment: It is still unbound: 

    Error: The variable AVG is unbound.
      1 (continue) Try evaluating AVG again.
      2 Specify a value to use this time instead of evaluating AVG.
      3 Specify a value to set AVG to.
      4 (abort) Return to level 0.
      5 Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

Comment: not sure what lisp you are using, but the line (setq avg (+ (avg) (aref testScore i))) should probably be: (setq avg (+ avg (aref testScore i))), avg is not a function without parameters but a local variable.

Comment: Same error.. updated the code btw.
Running Common Lisp in Clozure CL.

Comment: @chemoBrain Now you have an extra parenthesis in your let clause (avg 0))**)** <- this one should cover until the end of the function, since you will use the avg variable afterwards, i.e. move the end parenthesis after the last dotimes is finished

Comment: Even if I take it apart as much as possible it is still unbound:  (let examScore 0)
 (let avg 0)

Comment: Can you try to copy & paste this: rextester.com/VRELQ7686 instead of your code and see if it works?

Comment: Got it, still error. This program turned into a pain in the ass.. :D
http://rextester.com/live/REO66770

Comment: (let avg (reduce #'+ testScore)) fixed it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Assigns sum of testScore array to avg variable.

```
(let avg (reduce #'+ testScore))
```

Edit:

```
(setq avg (/ (reduce #'+ testScore) 7))
```

Comment: No it doesn't.. `let` in CL has the format  `(let ((binding expression) ...) body ...)` and thus in your code it seems `avg` shoudl ahve been a list of bindings and the body is `(reduce...)`

Comment: Than what is your suggestion?